# Current Page Name

Tags: php

I am new in php. I want to show the current page name as my page title. So I used...

```
<?php echo ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)); ?>
```

Now I want to show the page title as "Home" if the "ucfirst" code returns "index" i.e. my index.php. So I tried to write a function.

```
function pagename() {
$pname = ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
if($pname == "Index") {
$pname = "Home";
}
return $pname;
}
```

But the problem is, it is not showing anything. I know my code is wrong, but I failed to understand where is wrong. Please help.

Comment: `if($pname == "Index")` does `index.php` file has first letter is capital ? if not change to `if($pname == "index")`

Comment: First check that what is return by `$pname`like index.php OR index.

Comment: I found my answer. Initially I used `<?php echo $pname; ?>` and this is the reason for not showing "Home". I replaced `$pname` with `pagename()` and got it. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it's giving me correct output. when i run it, I get "**Index**" as return value. maybe you should see that you are printing **$pname** correctly or not in the application :) Good luck